# Ubuntu not detecting Windows 10 operating system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Well I didin't find many answers to this question. I've Windows 10 as my primary OS. But I want to try my hands on Ubuntu (Linux). I had 2 partitions in my system C and D. I created a 98GB unallocated space and created a 3rd partition for installing Ubuntu into it. But during the installation process the installation process fails to detect my Windows 10 operating system and gives the option to delete everything. I want to keep an option of Windows 10 with myself which is why I cannot delete Windows OS.

I've already done the "uncheck fast start" thing but unfortunately it didn't help.

Please help with this

Comment: sounds like the CD is booting Legacy mode when windows is installed in EFI mode. is this a 64-bit computer? are you sure you have a 64-bit EFI image for ubuntu?

Comment: Did you create partition with Windows? Windows cannot create Linux compatible partitions, and often converts from basic to Microsoft proprietary dynamic partitions. Then Linux cannot work with Windows. Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l` and/or screenshot from Windows partitioning tool.

Comment: @ravery Yes-64 bit. I installed ubuntu from the Ubuntu website 16.04.2LTS version.

Comment: @oldfred Yeah I created the partition using Windows Create and Format Hard disk Partition. Ca you please explain me your last sentence

Comment: @varunsharma -- go into system settings and turn off legacy support. see if you get efi mode on the installer

Comment: @oldfred I cannot post the screenshot of `sudo  parted -l` here.

Comment: @ravery I couldn't find legacy support/option

Comment: Just copy & paste terminal output into post above so you can preserve formatting. If in comments, it will essentially be unreadable.

Comment: Mistakenly booting in the wrong mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) is unlikely to produce the symptoms described. I don't recommend messing with those settings yet, since doing so might create new problems. Instead, it's best to get the diagnostic information requested by oldfred. Also, note that both many EFIs and Windows have options called "Fast Startup" (or something similar). It's the *Windows* feature that *must* be disabled. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932807/why-is-ubuntu-forcing-me-to-manually-partion-my-drive) for a recent question that may be related to your problem.